# Using scala, how do I compare two class types when one has a $ at the end?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to compare the class type of a SparkSQL query.

```
scala> val plan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan("create table some_table as select 1")
scala> val childClass = plan.children.map(_.getClass).toList(0)

Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan] = class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project
```

So looks like its of the type `class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project`, however, I get `false` when I compare this using `isInstanceOf`.

```
scala> childClass.isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project]
                                                                                                                                           ^
res9: Boolean = false
```

I think the problem here is how the class `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project` is being compiled.

```
scala> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.getClass
res21: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.type] = class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project$
```

The `$` sign at the end is causing issues. However, if I do `childClass.getName` and do a string compare with the class, I get `true` but I don't think that's a good way of doing a class comparison here.

This is more of a scala question than a Spark question and the problem seems trivial but I can't seem to figure out how to compare the class type without comparing the raw string name itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.getClass` calls the `getClass` method of the companion object for `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project` which is a singleton instance of the class `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project$` (in this case, looking at Spark's code shows that to be a `case class` with a synthetic companion object).

You can get the class object for `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project` with:

```
classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project]
```

i.e.

```
childClass.getClass == classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project]
```

should be true.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Levi, really helped me understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I'm still a little confused though, I don't see a companion object for `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project` in the spark code. I only see a case class. How did you deduce that `getClass` is referring to the companion object?

Comment: It's a `case class`, so the Scala compiler synthesizes a companion object (mainly for the `apply` (for object construction as a function) method).